# How to make use of POST request in the right way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, http-post

I've written some code to grab data from a webpage. The site has got dropdown options to choose preferable items. So, firstly i made a `GET` request to form the url and then a `POST` request. I've managed to parse the data from it's first page only but the populated results display across several pages. When I change the page number in form data parameter, it doesn't have any effect on the result. I still get the result from the first page. How can I get them all? Btw, I didn't choose anything from dropdown options on basis of my preference ; rather, I initiated a search how the default preference is already set.

Link to that site: [URL](https://www.fbo.gov/index)

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload={

    's':'opportunity',
    'mode':'list',
    'tab':'list',
    'pageID':3
}

r = requests.get("replace_with_above_url",params=payload,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

payload={

    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][_posted_date]':'90',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][set_aside][]':'',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][zipstate]':'',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][procurement_type][]':'',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][keywords]':'',
    'autocomplete_input_dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][agency]':'',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][agency]':'',
    'so_form_prefix':'dnf_',
    'dnf_opt_action':'search',
    'dnf_opt_template':'vendor_procurement_notice_filter',
    'dnf_opt_mode':'update',
    'dnf_opt_finalize':'0',
    'dnf_opt_target':'',
    'dnf_opt_validate':'1',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][dnf_class_name]':'procurement_notice',
    'clear_filters_from_home':'1'   
}

res = requests.post(r.url,data=payload, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".solt"):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server 'remembers' your search with a *session cookie*. Your code discards all cookies returned by the server, so the memory is reset each time you make a new request.

Use a [*session object*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to record incoming cookies, and send them out again with subsequent requests:

```
with requests.Session() as sess:
    sess.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    r = sess.get("replace_with_above_url", params=payload)

    # ...

    res = sess.post(r.url, data=payload)
```

You can then submit `GET` requests for the `/index?s=opportunity&mode=list&tab=list&pageID=` URLs with numeric page ids starting at `1`, until you encounter an empty result set:

```
page_id = 0
page_url = 'https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&mode=list&tab=list&pageID={}'
while True:
    page_id += 1 
    page = sess.get(page_url.format(page_id))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
    rows = soup.select('.solr-lst table tr')
    if len(rows) <= 1:
        break
    for row in rows[1:]:
        print([c.get_text(strip=True) for c in rows[1].select('td')])
```

Comment: Thanks sir Martijn Pieters, for your answer. You are very close. I'm getting lots of duplicates. I don't know if it is generated because of my script. However, I'm pasting here a link where you can see my attempt to organize your suggested portion to make a go. Just give me any suggestion as to whether I did it accordingly or anything should fall outside `with` block. And last of all whether this `if not rows:break` portion the way I used in my script will do. Thanks. Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=For+sir+Martijin.txt

Comment: @Topto: that link doesn't actually lead anywhere, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Topto: I've adjusted the last page detection; there is at least 1 row (with headers) for an empty page.

Comment: Sorry sir. Now check it out. I hope it will work now: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rq8rhmyz4nwvfep/For%20sir%20Martijin.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Topto: yes, the indendation is correct; you are still using the same session object to load the pages. I've adjusted the `rows` test already; you could also just load the `soup.select('.solr-lst table tr td')` cells, but then you lose the row grouping; I'd loop over each row and extract the separate `td` cells from those.

Comment: Your code is already working. It is my incapability that I can't adjust it the way it should be. I meant the full code. That is why I pasted the above link for your consideration.

Comment: Thanks sir. I will accept your answer when time is right. Btw, if I encounter any issue I will let you know.

Comment: Sir Martijn Pieters, a last question to get the clarity of one thing: in your first portion of suggested script, you used `res = sess.post(r.url, data=payload)` in the last line. However, I didn't find this `res` reused later. Was this `res` a just place holder? Slightly confused. Thanks sir for your time.

Comment: @Topto: `res` is just the response object from the HTTP POST request made. Use it to verify that the request was successful, or just don't assign it and not use it.

Comment: Thanks sir for the clarity. This is what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the site through web console reveals that hitting search button issues a POST request complete with query string and form data parameters, while clicking on a page anchor, beneath, starts a GET request, with query string only (and pageID param set accordingly).

I edited your code adding a `run` function, which takes page id as `page` argument and issues a POST if `page` equals 1, a GET otherwise:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload={

    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][_posted_date]':'90',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][set_aside][]':'',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][zipstate]':'',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][procurement_type][]':'',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][keywords]':'',
    'autocomplete_input_dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][agency]':'',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][agency]':'',
    'so_form_prefix':'dnf_',
    'dnf_opt_action':'search',
    'dnf_opt_template':'vendor_procurement_notice_filter',
    'dnf_opt_mode':'update',
    'dnf_opt_finalize':'0',
    'dnf_opt_target':'',
    'dnf_opt_validate':'1',
    'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][dnf_class_name]':'procurement_notice',
    'clear_filters_from_home':'1',
}
def run(page):
    url = "the given url"
    query = {
        's': 'opportunity',
        'mode': 'list',
        'tab': 'list',
        'pageID': page
    }
    if(page==1):
        r = requests.get(url, params=query, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        res = requests.post(r.url,data=payload, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    else:
        res = requests.get(url, params=query, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".solt"):
        print(item.text)

for page in range(10):
    run(page + 1)
```

This code yelds 200 lines, i.e. 10 pages with 20 results per page.